# Is there a package to decrease margins?

Tags: margins, paper-size

I know about `geometry` and `savetrees`, but what I have in mind is something else.  I'd like to be able to `\usepackage` something that would leave the size of the text block but decrease the margins (equivalently paper size), so that a pdf viewer that is set to "fit to width" or even "fit to page" would display as much as possible without wasting screen real estate (which - contrary to the situation with paper - is *extremely* expensive in terms of productivity, especially when I have a laptop screen with moderate resolution) on the one hand and additional scaling on the other (which is a bit cumbersome as I don't "focus" my pdf viewer).

Comment: `\documentclass{standalone}` leaves no margins, but I'm guessing this is not quite what you are looking for?

Comment: It leaves them for me...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I tried `\usepackage{standalone}`. Of course, `\documentclass{standalone}` is no use - I want to preserve all settings of e.g. `amsart` (text block size among other things). Thanks anyway.

Comment: `geometry` lets you set the paper size as well, so if you do some calculations, I suppose it wouldn't be hard to get very small margins with the same textblock. You can find some useful numbers with `\documentclass{amsart}  
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}`.

Comment: Why not just `\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. The point of my question is that I do not *want* to perform any calculations. I have a computer for that;-). I want to be able to just drop `\usepackage{killmargins}` (with any documentclass) and have it done.

Comment: @Werner: because it changes the textblock size and keeps the papersize. I want the reverse.

Comment: On a viewer like SumatraPDF, this is called `fit to contents`. I suppose many other viewers have this functionality.

Comment: @Bernard: nice, though pdf-tools does not have it.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a trick

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\edef\mtht{\the\textheight}
\edef\mtwd{\the\textwidth}
\usepackage[paperwidth=\mtwd,paperheight=\mtht,text={\mtwd,\mtht}]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-14]
\end{document}
```

**Edit**
It could be better with `\let`

```
\let\mtht\textheight
\let\mtwd\textwidth
```

one can make small margins

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=1.04\mtwd,paperheight=1.02\mtht,text={\mtwd,\mtht}]{geometry}
```

---

**Update** following comments below, one can  try

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=\dimexpr\mtwd+0.5cm\relax,
            paperheight=\dimexpr\mtht+2cm\relax,
            text={\mtwd,\mtht}]{geometry}
```

---

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\edef\mtht{\the\textheight}
\edef\mtwd{\the\textwidth}

\usepackage[paperwidth=\dimexpr\mtwd+0.5cm\relax,
            paperheight=\dimexpr\mtht+1.5cm\relax,
            text={\mtwd,\mtht},
            top=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-14]
\end{document}
```

Comment: the first version looks safer (the `\let` version depends on the order geometry sets things internally, I didn't look to check.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you're right i forgot this point (may be better means  shorter or quicker :-))  i did not look too,  but it seems natural or let's hope that.

Comment: very cute!  i have tested this with an actual submission to an ams journal, and found a small problem.  it cuts off anything that descends below the baseline of the last text line on a page; this includes descenders, some math subscripts, and the page number on the first page; it would also cut off anything produced by `\enlargethispage`.  and it would cut off any overfull boxes at the right; but that might reasonably be ignored.  however, the length really *is* a problem; add the equivalent of two baselines, and i think you're good.

Comment: more testing with actual submission.  the top is a bit tight to the running head, and there's also more space than needed at the bottom.  if you change the options for `geometry` to be `paperheight=\dimexpr\mtht+1.5cm` and add `top=1cm` the result is nicely centered with just a bit of "air" on all sides.  since the folio on the first page is a drop folio, that automatically leaves a bit more than one blank line on other pages, which would easily accommodate an `\enlargethispage{1\baselineskip}`.  (i'm saving this for future reference.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you again and  feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: thanks for your suggestions and testing!

Comment: @touhami: great, why won't you turn your solution into a package?

Comment: @mbork -- although a package would be good, i'm not sure that what works here for `amsart` and other ams classes would work for the basic latex classes, never mind for classes like those in the koma collection, or `memoir`.  the ams classes have a very particular (some would say "peculiar") mechanism for establishing the placement of material on the imaging surface, governed by the requirements of our in-house print shop, where the pdf output is imaged directly onto printing plates for the press.